# Integration control of transaction for hibernate in using spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

Here is a simple dao function and my appllicationContext.xml

```
<beans>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.efrei"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClass}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.efrei.st2ee.entity"/>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>

                <prop key="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
                <!--                sql dialect-->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
                </prop>

                <!--                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>-->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
           
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- enable transaction annotation support -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

   
</beans>
```

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public int updateStudent(Student student) throws RuntimeException{
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
//        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        String queryString = "update Student set firstName=:firstNamewhere sId=:sId";
        Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
        .......
        int res = query.executeUpdate();
//        transaction.commit();
        return res;
    }
```

I add @Transcation on the UpdateStudent() but it still throws out
`javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`

only when I add explicitly

`Transcation transcation = session.getTranscation;  content.. tr.commit;`

inside the code it works.

So is there a way to leave spring to control the transaction?

Comment: Could you add your configuration file? Transactions should be enabled with `@EnableTransactionManagement` when using java config or with `<tx:annotation-driven/>` when using XML.

Comment: i added the applicationContext.xml normally it's correct

Comment: I suppose, hibernate session should be created using `getCurrentSession()` instead of `openSession()`. Former one can use session opened by spring, latter one opens new session.

Comment: ok i've tried and it's finally worked thank you , and i found out that when i add <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>  because i saw that in tutorial for hibernate for activate ``getCurrentSession()``, and the problem occurs again.you the what's the inside relation of thoses things?